# What's the quickest "boost food" whilst riding in a fast bunch?

Tags: road-bike, nutrition

I am starting to ride with a bunch of cyclists doing on average 40 to 50k.
My personal average is around mid 30s to 45k/hr.
Aside from proper training, exercise and leg muscles, what food do you recommend to give you a **quick energy boost** to be able to keep up with the bunch?
I was told Mars Bars are quick energy sources, but high in the bad stuff. Any other more natural recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: The traditional food is bananas. They work well, if you like them. They come in a handy container too - bite off the top and squeeze from the bottom.

Comment: Yip, I ride in a fast enough local bunch averaging 32-35kph over 70km rolling terrain most weekends, lots of half eaten bananas poking out of jersey pockets... Another option is not eating, just have something sweet in your water.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some personal thoughts/opinions:

- If you're not riding much longer than an hour or so, you might not need much. Perhaps a sports/electrolyte drink that contains sugars will suffice and be convenient.
- I use mainly cheap gel bars for a sugar hit, but they get quite boring and eat away at your teeth. Flapjack, oats, etc are good for a bit of variety but perhaps more appropriate for longer rides as they release energy slower.
- Cereal bars can be quite dry and difficult to get down especially if you're a bit dehydrated.
- Something with caffeine may be of benefit (caffeine on its own doesn't have energy, but it can give you a boost). I'd drink some strong coffee before the ride. Caffeine has a half-life of approximately 5 to 6 hours.
- Trial and error is key!

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE]. The OP was asking about foods, not drugs. Caffeine cannot *supply* energy.

Comment: Ridiculous. You down-voted my answer because I suggested "something with caffeine" as just one part of my answer? "Something" referred to a caffeinated gel or similar. Caffeine gives you a boost, which is what the OP is looking for and therefore a relevant part of my answer. It's not like I suggested injecting an amp of caffeine during the ride instead of ingesting something.

Comment: Look on the bright side: I explained why I down voted, so you know what to improve. Other people may not think the same as me and upvote.

Comment: The bright side is that your "explanation" demonstrated that you did not read my post in its entirety. Other people are very welcome to go ahead and upvote - there is nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: I see someone else agrees with you. That's how it works. You can check out examples of good answers in almost anything written by [Kibbee](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/163/kibbee), [Batman](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/8219/batman), [mattnz](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/3924/mattnz), or [Mσᶎ](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/7044/mσᶎ).

Comment: Sometimes you get downvoted, other times you get upvoted - thats the way it goes. Energy drinks tend to make some people uncomfortable due to the caffeine, carbonation and sugar (if its not something like red bull sugar free or whatever).

Comment: So in the first bullet, by energy drink I was referring to standard (non caffeinated) energy drink - you know, the tubs of powder stuff. As you write, people tolerate food/drink differently, particularly when their bodies are under stress - hence my comment about trial and error. Who'd have thought on a cycling forum that mentioning caffeine would attract so much attention! :S

Comment: Perhaps you should change some of the wording. For most people, "energy drink" would refer to something like Red Bull or Monster. A better word to use might be "Sports Drink" or "Electrolyte Drink" which most people would associate with Gatorade, Powerade, or Cytomax.  As far as the caffeine recommendation, it doesn't give you energy. It can put your body into a state where it uses more energy, but if that energy isn't there, it isn't going to help much. Might even cause further problems because your body will be using exta energy for non-cycling related functions.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment - I've edited accordingly. I never suggested caffeine on its own but perhaps trying caffeinated gels or sports drink might be worth a shot to see if they result in the extra boost the marketing claims.

Comment: I have upvoted you because I too think some people in here a precious with their down-voting, especially when they don't explain why but more seriously, I gave you the final YES of approval, as it answers pretty much what I already knew and expected. I just wanted to see what other opinions held and advised, which all have been good btw. Thank you everyone. I think in the early morning before I go on my rides with these guys is to eat something - like a bowl of cereal and some minor fruit or even a bananana, and then take two gels which should cover me for an hour's ride.

Comment: .. and one thing I started doing to save money is making my own "gels" out of mashed pasta with a mix of yoghurt, fruit and chocolate. It works a treat!

Comment: Thanks v much :) I'm in Australia too and gels are so expensive in the LBS. I buy mine in bulk online but if you send your recipe I might give that a whirl. What do you put your homemade gels into for taking on rides?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure you are after "The quickest Boost food" - seems the problem you have is likely to be over an extended period. If your problem is say "they leave me behind up big hills" then maybe a "boost" is what you are after, but if its just keeping up over the duration of the ride, quick boost food is not good.

The problem with the likes of Jelly beans, honey etc is the quick boost is followed by an energy crash - often of disproportionate proportions to the boost you got. These sources have a place - but generally should only be used when the finish line is in site and only when you know how the affect you.

Bananas, energy bars and  gels are usually better as they have more complex carbs that release the energy over a longer time and reduce the effects of the low sugar crash. These should be used before you feel the need for them, so the energy is there when its needed, and ideally consumed regularly in small amounts - if needed set a repeating timer and eat when it beeps - every 10-20 minutes.

As everyone is different, the best advise is to try different foods and choose one you like, and different frequencies and amounts - most people do better on small and often. Do this before you need it - some gels make me want to vomit when working hard, others work really well for me. If you have one that disagrees with you, best its not when you are not trying to keep up with a bunch.

Comment: `when the finish line is in site` speaking figurativevly, right? I feel that a chocolate bar provides energy for at least an hour.

Comment: Chocolate is high in fat with a bit of sugar - the fat keeps you going longer, the sugar gives you a boost -  so chocolate does not fit into the Jelly bean (simple sugar) food group.

Answer (score 4):

Energy gels such as [GU Energy gels](http://guenergy.com/guenergygel-original.html) are a pretty common quick acting energy source.

For a more natural source, you could try [honey](http://capilano.com.au/products/australia/honey-shotz/)

Comment: My understanding is that GU Gels take longer than jelly beans for example because of their dissolving factor. Being a gel, they simply take longer to dissolve in your system and act more like pasta than anything else. Honey is a great idea though!

Answer (score 4):

Mars Bars are not that great for cycling. Yes, they have quite a lot of calories, so will give you some energy. But most of that is simple sugars, so it may be a quick energy boost, but soon followed by an energy crash. Also Mars Bars have quite a lot of fat (about 17g per 100g), so this can not be easily digested while cycling hard - it could just make you sick.

Mars Bars are not very practical either. On a warm day, a bar in your back pocket will probably melt, so become rather messy and difficult to eat.

Answer (score 4):

What are the other cyclists in your group eating?  I go out for similarly long rides, and most people don't eat anything on the ride.  I would say to make sure you are well fed (but not overly full) before the ride starts, and you probably won't feel the need to eat something for the ride. 50 KM at an average speed of 35 km/h will mean that the ride is over in an hour and a half.  Bring a bottle with Gatorade or similar to keep your electrolytes up, and possibly another bottle of just water for those times when you feel like just having water.

Also, if you are going to eat something, eat small amounts on a regular basis, and don't wait until you feel like you need more energy.  By that time it's already too late.  The same goes for water. Drink before you start to feel thirsty.  Get to know your own body and how much water/food you're going to need for a particular length and difficulty of ride so that your body doesn't end up with a deficit during the ride.

Answer (score 3):

[Skratchlabs](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjjMIwv6nCG4jYCXM8tWvvg) has made a series of youtube videos for lots of types of food for different types of energy. You may want to thumb through them in order to find something which works for you (your stomach may not agree with everything).

One thing I particularly like about the Skratchlabs videos is that they have a nice way of packaging *real* foods in foil so you can eat while riding.

Cliff makes Cliff Shot Bloks and companies make similar energy gel type products which you may want to try as well.

Answer (score 2):

I typically eat Powerbars or gels like GU if I need more intake on the bike. Additionally, I have a electrolyte mix like Cytomax in my water bottles which keeps me ingesting salts and calories. Bananas are also great, though I eat so many post-ride that I typically don't eat them on the bike unless it's a really long ride.

If you're slowly eating throughout the ride, I see no reason to need a "quick boost".

Answer (score 2):

I find that on a longish ride, if I grab a chocolate milk at a quick stop at a convenience store, it keeps me ahead of the dreaded bonk.

Comment: This is a good example of alternative thinking, but others should keep in mind that it’s not for everyone. A good bit of the world population is lactose intolerant and they might not digest chocolate milk easily. That said, I do know one ultra endurance athlete who swears by chocolate milk.

Comment: If it works for you that's great (I love chocolate milk) - but personally there's no way i could stomach hard riding on anything milky

Answer (score 1):

It's about keeping your energy up NOT about somehow generating 5kmph more from food. You'll go faster through training but it won't help if you bonk half way through a ride. I tend to "fuel" up before a ride then eat as I go along; usually rice cakes or cereal bars. For a bit of emergency energy if I'm flagging I'll go with a gel (some give me cramps tho) or something like shot bloks. However I can say with confidence that if I'd eaten properly as I rode, I'd never have needed them.

As an aside, if your AVERAGE speed on a solo ride is 35-45kmph, I'd start racing pretty; that is pretty quick.

Comment: My average is around 40 to be more precise. Yes that's fast by most average rider standards, but a lot of the guys here are faster believe me. I have not asked them yet what they eat though, but that is a good start.

Comment: Given the average speed of a pro peloton on a flattish stage is around 40-45kmph that's impressive.

Answer (score 1):

my list of favourite energy bombs (some are not very portable and some others you may not be able to easily find them in your country):

- brown bread with honey
- brown bread with [tahini (sesame pulp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahini)
- peanut butter
- banana
- dried fruits and nuts
- [compressed sesame with honey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_seed_candy)

Answer (score 1):

I have a preference for squares of **chocolate** on a hard race.  Trick is to break them up  into squares, leave them in the freezer overnight, remember to take them in the morning.  You can mash them against the ceiling of your mouth and still breathe perfectly well.  Plain chocolate or goo-filled works nicely.

I also find **hard boiled lollies** work as a sugar source.  They can be crammed into a cheek like a squirrel, when an effort is needed.

Either of those, eaten 5-10 minutes before an effort definitely help.

One surprising boostery-type food is **Mint Cake**.  It has a mild peppermint/menthol-like way of clearing the breathing passages, so like a car with a blower/supercharger, you suddenly get more clear air in the lungs, which is helpful in recovery and oxygenating yourself.

**Gels** have their place, but they're not filling so you do need something to sit in the stomach and provide some base.   **Bliss balls** are okay - something you can eat in one or two bites maximum.  Some people like **rice cakes** for this

Do remember your **water** too - being hydrated is more important than being fed.  You might choose two bottles, with one of chilled water and the other of water+electrolyte mix.  Personally I just take water, sometimes with ice in it for the first hour.   Staying hydrated will help with your overall condition throughout the ride.

---

Avoid chocolate with nuts in it, they can cause an airway obstruction as you inhale while chewing (Momma says "shut your mouth while chewing" but table manners don't matter on the bike)

Avoid things with complex wrapping - Personally I dislike bananas on the bike because you need to open them.  Same goes for individually-wrapped items, I'd rather have a pottle of items, perhaps in a top-tube bag.

Avoid dry muesli bars too - they can go down the wrong pipe into your lungs and cause a coughing fit.  These bars are nice, but not suitable for a ride:
[image]

---

Lastly you can work on your technique.  Feel free to skip a turn on the front, and hang at the back for a cycle to recover.  Everyone has a bad day, and there's nothing wrong with taking a 2 minute breather at the back if you have to.  Even taking a 10 second pull instead of a 30 second pull can help you keep up and not be shattered.

For more ideas, look around your group-mates.  See what they're eating, and also when they eat.  Being ready for the next climb in sufficient time is important too.

Side point, don't litter while riding.  Noone likes a rider who intentionally drops their stuff for any reason.